# How to remove element from array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have little problem with my code. I push the value of an input in an empty array, and i display the value in a html list with a remove button.

But when i remove the value in html, the array still holds the value. I used `arr.splice(0, 1)` but it doesn't remove the specific value. Example:

My html list looks like:

- v1
- v2
- v3

My array after the list is filled:

```
array = [v1, v2, v3]
```

When i remove `v2` in html my array doesn't changes. I'm new to JavaScript.

My code in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/niqulomuse/edit?html,js,console,output) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15mdjdpa/).

---

im sorry my english is not very nice

https://jsfiddle.net/15mdjdpa/

```js
var taches = [];
var saisie;
var ecran;
var liste;
var organiz;
var j= 0;


function run(){
  saisie= document.getElementById('champ').value;
  taches.push(saisie);
  
  ecran = document.getElementById('afficheur');
  var liste = document.getElementById('listes');
  
  console.log("taches :", taches);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.setAttribute("id", "lisupr");
  var btn = document.createElement('Button');
  btn.textContent="X";
  btn.addEventListener("click",function supr (){ 
    liste.removeChild(li);
    
        taches.splice(0,1);
        console.log("tableau taches: "+ taches);
      
    
    
  } );
  
  li.innerText= saisie + " "+" ";

  console.log("saisie "+saisie);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  liste.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<input type ="text" id="champ" onfocus="javascript:this.value=''" class="form-control ">
  <button type="button" onclick ="run()" class="btn btn-primary"  >send</button>


  <div id="afficheur"><h4> list : </h4>
    <ul id="listes"> </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Question is unclear.  Please work on formatting your english correctly.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/niqulomuse/edit?html,js,console,output in jsbin also sorry

Comment: im french and my english is not good

Comment: you are removing the ith list element, but always removing the first element from the array, so you are not removing the same things in dom and your array

Comment: yes exactly How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `v2` from `array`, do like this.

```
var index = array.indexOf(v2);
if(index != -1) array.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: that wasn´t available

Comment: @AmiraFathallah which is not available ?

Comment: my problem if i remove in html i want my array remove the same element automatically, this code don't remove a correct element

Comment: Yes, your problem is that you are splicing the first element in the array.  But you need to identify the index of the item you want to delete.  You can't actually do an indexOf because you could easily have 2 of the exact same thing in a list.  I'll give you an answer....

Answer (score -1):

I'd rewrite this code using jQuery.  I'd remove all the ids - you can make the edits relative to the button being clicked.  Which would let you have more than one of these on a page, among other things.

HTML:

```
<div class="module">
  <input class="item" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-add">add</button>
  <ul class="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Here's the script:

```
var list = [],
  addToList = function(target,item){
    list.push(item);
    target
      .append(
        $('<li>')
          .html(item)
          .append(
            $('<button>')
              .addClass('js-delete m-l')
              .html('X')
          )
      )

  }
$('.js-add').click( function(){
  var parent = $(this).parent(),
    item = parent.find('input.item');
  addToList(parent.find('ul.list'),item.val());
  item.val('');
})
$('.module').on( 'click', '.js-delete', function(){
  var parent = $(this).parent(),
    index = $('li').index( parent );
  list.splice(index,1);
  parent.remove();
  console.log(list);
})
```

Actually, if you want to make it so you can add multiple lists, you actually need to nest the 'list' array in an object or array, and have something reference it, probably inside the module div.

Your issue is what Angular does automatically - without all the management.  It binds the html content to the json array so all you need to do is change the array value, or delete it.  The HTML would immediately reflect the change.

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/yducyt83/

Comment: thank's  but the code not working i used link of jquery

Comment: hunh.  I did a jsfiddle for this.  Loks like I forgot to include it.  here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/yducyt83/